# Rails: Why do I get a 204 response from all but the first request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have a button on my homepage. When clicked it makes a POST request to `forms_controller` so that a new form is created.

My button:

```
<%= link_to 'Add form', forms_path, id: 'add_form_button',
                                 class: 'btn btn-primary',
                                method: :post, remote: true %>
```

When the request is completed, a message is logged to the console:

```
<script>
  $('#add_form_button').on('ajax:complete', function(){
    console.log('Request complete!');
    });
</script>
```

This is the action:

```
def create
  current_user.forms.create
end
```

My routes are defined like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'home#show'
  resources :forms, except: [:index]
  get 'user_forms' => 'partials#user_forms'
end
```

It works as expected. Each time I click the button, a new form is created and the message is logged to the console.

However, after the form is created, I want to reload a div so that I can see the newly created form listed with any others:

```
$('#add_form_button').on('ajax:complete', function(){
  console.log('Request complete!')
  var user_forms = '#user_forms';
  $(user_forms).load('user_forms',function(){
    document.getElementById('add_form_button').scrollIntoView();
  });
});
```

In the case of `.load('user_forms')...`, `user_forms` is a route to an action that I have created to return a partial:

```
class PartialsController < ApplicationController
  def user_forms
    render partial: 'home/user_forms'
  end
end
```

The first time the button is clicked, it works as expected: a new form is created, the message is logged to the console and the div is reloaded with the partial so that it lists the newly created form.

But it doesn't work on subsequent clicks. New forms *are* created on each click of the button but the div does not reload nor is the message logged to the console. I also see the following error in the Rails terminal:

```
No template found for FormsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 454ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

I understand that I have not defined an explicit response in `forms_controller#create` but I don't understand why it works the first time and not subsequent times. What is stopping it from working a second time?

Comment: Hi, I assume you use Rails 5?It returns 204 by default if no template is provided. See https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/07/03/controller-actions-default-no-content-in-rails-5-if-template-is-missing.html for more info. It's not error per se. Other than that, I don't see any other problem with what you provided. Can you post what's in `routes.rb`? Also is there no other js code interacting with DOM or listen to ajax events?

Comment: That's the only JS on the page. I'll edit my question to add the routes.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I whipped up a quick example(using what you provided), and it works fine for me. Notice you should only see 2 requests for each click. Do you see other warnings, errors?

[image]

I made a simple `user_form` partial to prove the form is ajax loaded.

```
<table>
  <% Form.all.each do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.id %></td>
      <td><%= f.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

So, your code is fine :). I'd recommend looking at other culprit like turbolink(it can mess up your ajax), custom js script etc.

Comment: Ah. For the first click, I see two requests: one POST and the subsequent GET for the partial. The following clicks only result in a POST request. That 204 is a red herring. It follows every POST request.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `FormsContoller#create` doesn't have a template. Because you didn't put an explicit `render` in that action, Rails is trying to find a template under `forms/create.html.erb`.

But of course you don't want to render a template for your create action because it's only responding to an AJAX post.

Try adding an explicit render at the end of the `FormsContoller#create` action. Something like `render {}, status: :ok`.

Not sure if that resolves your form rendering issue but at least that should resolve the `No template found` error.

Comment: Normally you don't even need `{}` in your content, so it can be `render nothing: true, status: :ok` or a nice shorthand for that is just `head :ok`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the premise of my question is completely wrong. I get a 204 after every click but a GET request with a 200 status follows the first click. I assumed the 200 was for the first POST. Kasperite's advice that I should see two requests for every click helped me realise the obvious.

I hadn't explained in my question that the button itself was in the `user_forms` partial that was being used to populate the reloaded the div. (If I'd mentioned it, I would have likely seen the problem straight away. Besides, the name I'd given the partial itself should have been a big enough clue it shouldn't have been in there.)

Whilst `$('#add_form_button').on('ajax:complete', function(){...}` works the first time, the original button is removed from the DOM and is replaced with an identical one.

However, since this is an entirely different element, the event listener is not attached to this new button.

I have solved the problem by simply placing the button outside of the partial.